# Shared access to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I allow shared access to multiple users on a EC2 instance (one user at a time)

Scenario:

I need to create a EC2 instance with some service running on it and all the developers will be using the same service. Time and again different developers will need to log into machine and access the services running on it.

My question is how can I allow multiple users (all have access to same AWS account) to access the ec2 instance which is created by me.

I am not sure whether this is even possible or not.

Edit: This question aims at windows instance. All the answers so far tend to go towards Linux.

Comment: Are you looking for providing console access to the instance or just to log in?

Comment: For the time being log in only.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create an IAM group and grant this group to access the EC2 instance. Then you can add users to the group. All users in the group will be able to access the instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_groups.html

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, this doesn't relate to AWS and it's simply providing shared access to a server.

1. Share the pem key you used at the creation of the EC2 instance, with the team (which I do not recommend)
2. Create accounts for the users, provide access via either password based or ssh-keys based (which I recommend; get their public keys and add those to the server) and grant them permissions accordingly (super users to sudoers etc.)

Comment: How do i do the same for windows instance?

Comment: 1. Just decrypt the password using the pem key and share it
2. Share the pem key itselff and ask them to log into the console and decrypt it themselves
**I don't recomment either of above**
3.Create a local user, grant the privileges you want and share the credentials along with the IP

Answer (score 0):

Since sharing ssh keys is not a good practice, my take on this would be to enable ssh login using passwords, instead of ssh keys. 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-password-login/